# When are Kotlin singletons (declared with the object modifier) instantiated?

Tags: singleton, kotlin

I can't find any information on when Kotling singletons are instantiated. I'm assuming it's the first time they are accessed but I can't confirm that anywhere.

```
object Singleton{
    val thing1 = 2
    val thing2 = "Hello"
}
```

When would this object be instantiated? When a property is first accessed? When something in the packaged is accessed? When the program is first run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html):

> - object declarations are initialized lazily, when accessed for the first time
> - object expressions are executed (and initialized) immediately, where they are used

Since you're using an object declaration (Your object has a name), it will be initialized lazily.